# WIA scanner, can't get/set 4104 and 6146 properties (color, color depth)

Tags: c#, .net, wia

I'm trying to configure the color and depth in a Kodak i2600 scanner using WIA on a C# project. Several posts refer to parameters 6146 (which can take the values ​​1 (color), 2 (gray scale) or 4 (white and black)) and 4104 (color depth = 24).

[WIA Automation for scanner color intent is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055572/wia-automation-for-scanner-color-intent-is-not-working)

[Windows image acquisition - setting device properties in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912303/windows-image-acquisition-setting-device-properties-in-c-sharp)

[Detect all available scanner resolutions using WIA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215453/detect-all-available-scanner-resolutions-using-wia)

These properties do not appear when I iterate the array scanner properties.

I use a foreach loop to iterate properties and this is the list that I get:

- 3112: User Name: *******
- 4098: Item Name: Root
- 4099: Full Item Name: 0000 \ Root
- 4101: Item Flags: 76
- 2: Unique Device ID: {613DD1FC6 - 810E- 1100 - 13EC7- 0800213E2092F} \ 0000
- 3: Manufacturer: Kodak
- 4: Description: KODAK i2600 Scanner
- 5: Type: 65537
- 6: Port: \ AUsbscan0
- 7: Name: KODAK i2600 Scanner
- 8: Server: local
- 9: Remote Device ID:
- 10: Ul Class ID: {40131AD10 - 3391 - 11D2- 9A33- 00C04FA36145}
- 11: Hardware Configuration: 0
- 12: 8audRate:
- 13: STI Generic Capabilities: 49
- 14: WIA Version: 2.0
- 15: Driver Version: 1.1.0.0
- 16: PnP ID String: usb=vid 040a&pid 601d=0000000000000000={6bddlfc6- 810f- 11d0- bec7- 0800 2be2092f}
- 17: STI Driver Version: 3
- 4125: Item Category: {F193526F- 5988- 4A26- 9888- E16E4F97CE10}
- 1026: Firmware Version: 0
- 3086: Document Handling Capabilities: 8229
- 3087: Document Handling Status: 5
- 3095: Max Scan Time: 3600000
- 3090: Horizontal Optical Resolution: 600
- 3091: Vertical Optical Resolution: 600
- 3103: Show preview control: 0
- 3098: Page Width: 8500
- 3099: Page Height: 14000
- 3096: Pages: 0
- 3076: Horizontal Sheet Feed Size: 8500
- 3077: Vertical Sheet Feed Size: 14000
- 3088: Document Handling Select: 1
- 3078: Sheet Feeder Registration: 1
- 3104: Minimum Horizontal Sheet Feed Size: 1000
- 3105: Minimum Vertical Sheet Feed Size: 1000
- 3100: Preview: 0

The scanner drivers are updated.

Comment: Can you share the links which referenced those properties ?

Comment: I've added some links which refer to these properties. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was with same problem (kodak i2400).

If you want, try this:

```
WIA.Item item = device.Items[1] as WIA.Item;

AdjustScannerSettings(item, 150, 0, 0, 1250, 1700, 0, 0, 1);


private static void AdjustScannerSettings(IItem scannnerItem, int scanResolutionDPI, int scanStartLeftPixel, int scanStartTopPixel,
        int scanWidthPixels, int scanHeightPixels, int brightnessPercents, int contrastPercents, int colorMode)
{
    const string WIA_SCAN_COLOR_MODE = "6146";
    const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6147";
    const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6148";
    const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6149";
    const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6150";
    const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6151";
    const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6152";
    const string WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS = "6154";
    const string WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS = "6155";

    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI, scanResolutionDPI);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI, scanResolutionDPI);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL, scanStartLeftPixel);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL, scanStartTopPixel);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS, scanWidthPixels);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS, scanHeightPixels);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS, brightnessPercents);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS, contrastPercents);
    SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_COLOR_MODE, colorMode);
}

private static void SetWIAProperty(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
{
    Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
    prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
}
```

Comment: Great! With your code I could set the color. I'm still stuck with the color depth configuration. Any ideas?